# Specify Path for the import Directive in C++

Tags: c++, import

I'm new to the c++ world. I read the import directive documentation to this directive on the Microsoft page. But I still don't understand how the import directive knows the location of the type libraries. Do I have to specify the Path to these Libraries in the Project Settings like for the Include Directive. Or how does this really work?

Thank you !!

Comment: See the __Remarks__ section (it looks clear to me) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: If [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019) is what you're talking about, it eventually follows the same path as the `include`

Comment: Thanks ! I obviously overlooked the remarks